# Load ResourceBundle depending on context

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have an application that is separated in several contexts with the same layout for each context but with different messages.

Example on context "A":

> TITLE
>
> Label: text

Example on context "B":

> TITLE B
>
> Label: text B

Note that the "Label" is the same on each context and context "A" is the default context.

I need to have one properties files per context:

- resources.properties (context A - default)

> title=TITLE
>
> label=Label
>
> text=text

- resources_b.properties (context B)

> title=TITLE B
>
> text=text B

And I would like to load the good property file depending on context.

The first solution I found is to use `Locale` like this:

```
// context is either "A", "B"...
resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(config, new Locale(context));
```

This way, if the message is not found in *resources_b.properties*, it will return the one from *resources.properties* as expected.

What could be the best way to have a "pretty" resource loading per context not using `Locale` ?

The application is currently only in English, but it may change in the future...

Comment: Why not Locale with its own variant: A/B/....

Comment: Why not load a different bundle for each context, but defini ng the same keys with different values?

Comment: @JBNizet It could be a good solution but it needs to always redefine all the keys when adding a new context
@JoopEggen I tested `variant` but all the property files must contains language code + country code, it's too restrictive

Comment: @kev, if you mean that you don't want to redefine all the keys that are common to all the contexts, then use a different, common bundle for those common keys.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the locale as context. You can rather have a locale variant like:

```
de_DE_<variant>, e.g., de_DE_A, de_DE_B
```

but note that a variant is not possible without a country.